# Parsing html tables with Jsoup in Android

Tags: android, html, json, parsing, jsoup

I'm new in android programming and in the use of jsoup. I'm trying to parse an html url and copy only the content between a pair of td tags, printing without the original formatation  each line under each line.. the url is http://tinyurl.com/63vmnwl. For example, i should get as output something like this:

SEGUNDA-FEIRA

Arroz/feijão preto/arroz integral

Frango assado

Cenoura com ervilha

Salada de almeirão

Opcional: Quibe de PVT

Goiabinha/refresco

Valor calórico de 1 refeição 1005 kcal

How can i do it?

EDIT: Sorry, i did not write part of the question
EDIT2: I'm still getting an error @user184994
Here's the logcat:

```
05-25 15:12:56.392: D/(1090): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb71f6cc0, tid 1090
05-25 15:12:56.572: W/EGL_emulation(1090): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-25 15:12:56.572: D/OpenGLRenderer(1090): Enabling debug mode 0
05-25 15:12:58.742: I/dalvikvm(1090): Could not find method org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect, referenced from method com.pcs3100.poliagenda.BandecoActivity.onCreate
05-25 15:12:58.742: W/dalvikvm(1090): VFY: unable to resolve static method 5662: Lorg/jsoup/Jsoup;.connect (Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/jsoup/Connection;
05-25 15:12:58.742: D/dalvikvm(1090): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000b
05-25 15:12:58.842: D/AndroidRuntime(1090): Shutting down VM
05-25 15:12:58.842: W/dalvikvm(1090): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4b00b90)
05-25 15:12:58.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1090): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 15:12:58.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1090): Process: com.pcs3100.poliagenda, PID: 1090
05-25 15:12:58.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1090): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup
05-25 15:12:58.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at com.pcs3100.poliagenda.BandecoActivity.onCreate(BandecoActivity.java:23)
05-25 15:12:58.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
05-25 15:12:58.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-25 15:12:58.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
05-25 15:12:58.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
05-25 15:12:58.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-25 15:12:58.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
05-25 15:12:58.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-25 15:12:58.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-25 15:12:58.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
05-25 15:12:58.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 15:12:58.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-25 15:12:58.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
05-25 15:12:58.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
05-25 15:12:58.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1090):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It's removed part of the question. Between what and what? thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking up how to use JSoup? I'm sure there's tutorials that explain this.

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339326/android-parse-html-with-jsoup)

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you mean:

```
    String url = "http://www.usp.br/coseas/cardapio.html";

    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements rows = doc.select("tr pre");

        for (Element elem: rows) {
           System.out.println(elem.text());
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output is:

```
SEGUNDA-FEIRA
Arroz/feijão preto/arroz integral
Copa lombo com molho de abacaxi
Virado de milho
Salada de acelga
Opcional: PVT à califórnia
Mexerica/refresco Valor calórico de 1 refeição 1195 kcal
```

Comment: I got some error message: "Unfortunately, PoliAgenda has stopped."

Comment: Can you post the log cat output please? I tested the code before I posted and it worked fine. Is it a network access on main thread exception?

Comment: i added the logcat in the question.

Comment: How did you go about adding Jsoup into your project? You've got `NoClassDefFoundError`

Comment: Okay, go to Project > Properties > Java Build Path, then click on the Order And Export tab, and finally, tick the box next to jsoup. That should get rid of the `NoClassDefFoundError`. After that, just make sure you're not trying to access the netword on the main thread, and finally, make sure you have the internet permission within your manifest.

Comment: Okay, i got rid of the NoClassDefFoundError. Now, how i make sure that i'm not trying to access the network on the main thread?

Comment: O thx SO MUCH!!! it worked!!! i used this "new Thread() {
@Override
public void run() {
//your code here
}
}.start();"  =) finally!! Now, how can i save it to a file? That website is updated every day, so the idea is to add an "Update Button" for do what that activity only if the button is clicked, but instead of printing to the console save it to a file in the cellphone, showing this file in another activity.